# Laravel 5.4 : Api route list

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, routes

I have the following lines in my `routes/api.php`

```
Route::middleware('api')->get('/posts', function (Request $request) {
    Route::resource('posts','ApiControllers\PostsApiController');
});
```

When I hit `http://localhost:8000/api/posts` it comes back blank, but when I move the above route to `routes/web.php` like so:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'],function(){
    Route::resource('posts','ApiControllers\PostsApiController');
});
```

it works.

As a reminder I have cleared the routes cache file with `php artisan route:clear` and my route list comes with `php artisan route:list` when my `routes/web.php` is empty and `routes/api.php` has the above route:

| Domain | Method | URI | Name | Action | Middleware |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | GET|HEAD | api/posts |  | Closure | api |

Note that with web routes part the list comes ok and works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: remove the middleware and try? dont use api middleware

Comment: but don't we need one ?

Comment: yes let me explain in my answer post

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dont use the middleware `api` and see following route example for API routes

**Example 1** (in your api.php)

```
Route::get('test',function(){
    return response([1,2,3,4],200);   
});
```

visit this route as

```
localhost/api/test
```

**Example 2** (if you want api authentication, token based auth using laravel passport)

```
Route::get('user', function (Request $request) {
    ///// controller
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

You can make get request for this route but you need to pass the access token because `auth:api` middleware has been used.

**Note:** see `/app/http/kernel.php`
and you can find the

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
//available route middlewares
]
```

There must not be such (api) kind of middle ware in this file (kernel.php) for routes unless you create one, that why you can not use middleware as `api`.

Here, How I am creating REST APIs (api.php)

```
//All routes goes outside of this route group which does not require authentication
Route::get('test',function(){
    return response([1,2,3,4],200);

});
//following Which require authentication ................
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::get('user-list',"Api\ApiController@getUserList");
    Route::post('send-fax', [
        'uses'=>'api\ApiController@sendFax',
        'as'=>'send-fax'
    ]);
    Route::post('user/change-password', [
        'uses'=>'api\ApiController@changePassword',
        'as'=>'user/change-password'
    ]);

});
```

Comment: Okay, Great, If i don't want to use passport, Then which one is preferable, JWT or Oauth2 ?

Comment: I have not used JWT, and passport is bassed on oauth ultimately, passport is just laravel easiest way to create oauth server. oauth is spec............see how oauth server works and what is passport all about.

Comment: of course, its the part of the framework, you can install using php artisan... please read this page https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport        ..............this is specially for oauth, its oauth but and laravel made easy to implement oauth server by creating a library package as "Passport" thats all